Is there a name for a line bundle whose tensor power has a nonvanishing cohomology
Is there a name for the following property of a line bundle $\mathcal L$ on a scheme $X$?
Property: There exist integers $n,m$ such that $H^n(X,\mathcal L^{\otimes m})\neq 0$.
For example, semi-ample line bundles satisfy the condition, but I could not find any more general name.
Thank you in advance.

I doubt there is such a name, because the meaning of nonvanishing may be totally different for different values of $n$. In particular the nonvanishing of $H^0$ means exactly that some power of $L$ has a nonzero global section, that is, $L$ is effective, whereas the nonvanishing of higher $H^i$ has no such direct interpretation in general.

Thank you so much for your comment!
